# Proving $I_{n+1,a}= \frac{2n-1}{2n} \cdot I_{n,a}$ given $I_{n,a}=\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+\frac{x^2}{a})^n}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

For $n \geq 1$, $a>0$ denote: $$I_{n,a}=\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+\frac{x^2}{a})^n}$$

Prove that the improper integral $I_{n,a}$ converges and satisfies: 
$$I_{n+1,a}= \frac{2n-1}{2n} \cdot I_{n,a}$$

I  managed to prove that $I_{n,a}$ converges but I'm having trouble with the  second part.

Comment: Does integration by parts not working???

Comment: Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396560/prove-int-infty-infty-fracdx1x2-an-converges/2396579#2396579

Comment: The answer below is faster.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

For the recursive formula,

write the numerator of $I_{n+1,a} $ as

$$1=1+\frac {x^2}{a}-\frac{x^2}{a} .$$

You will find that
$$I_{n+1,a}=$$
$$=I_{n,a}-\frac {1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\frac {\frac {2x}{a}}{(1+\frac {x^2}{a})^{n+1}}dx $$
$$=I_{n,a}-\frac {1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}u (x)v'(x)dx $$

with
$$u (x)=x $$ and
$$v (x)=-\frac {1}{n}\frac {1}{(1+\frac {x^2}{a})^n}.$$

To finish, use by parts integration.